# Undefined method NoMethodError

Tags: ruby

I was just playing around w/Ruby and attempting to create a function but for some reason it is not working the way I thought it would. Not sure why I'm having this problem but here is my code :

```
class Script
  print "Enter a number: "
  number = gets

  def random (temp)
      puts "#{temp}"
      puts "inside function"
  end

  random (number)
end
```

Error :

```
Script.rb:13:in `<class:Script>': undefined method `random' for Script:Class (NoMethodError)
from Script.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

Comment: What's the way you thought it would be? I run it and there's no error.

Comment: wtf...that's so strange. Its still not working and I've copy pasted all my code.

Comment: I'm actually pretty sure it is not working. Try it now again. I doubt its going to the actual function.

Comment: Why would you make such a simple program into a class? It makes no sense to do that. When you're "playing around w/Ruby" you really don't need to make a class for procedural code like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that you defined the `random` method as an instance method, but call it on the class level. You have two options to fix this:

Make it a class method (note the `self`):

```
class Script
  def self.random(temp)
    puts "#{temp}"
    puts "inside function"
  end

  print "Enter a number: "
  number = gets

  random(number)
end
```

Or change the method to create an instance first (note the `new`):

```
class Script
  def random(temp)
    puts "#{temp}"
    puts "inside function"
  end

  print "Enter a number: "
  number = gets

  new.random(number)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`random` is an instance method, not a class method, so your script raised NoMethodError, you should create a object of Script class then invoke random method.

```
class Script
  print "Enter a number: "
  number = gets

  def random (temp)  # it is a instance method.
      puts "#{temp}"
      puts "inside function"
  end

  Script.new.random(number)
end
```

or defined the `random`method as a class method.

```
class Script
  print "Enter a number: "
  number = gets

  def self.random (temp)  # define random as a class method
      puts "#{temp}"
      puts "inside function"
  end

  random(number)
end
```